# Can I make console command with several nonrequied parameters?

Tags: laravel

In laravel 9.6 app I have a console command with several parameters :

```
class MakeCustomModelCommand extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'make:custom-model {name} {userRelation} {productRelation} {categoryRelation} {fillableFromDb} {castingFields}';
    ...
```

Which was created with command :

```
php artisan make:command MakeCustomModelCommand
```

But when I run the command with some of the params missing, I got error :

> Not enough arguments (missing: "fillableFromDb, castingFields").

If there is a way to mark some parameters as nonrequired ?

Comment: use `?` sign to accept optional argument. like: `{user?}` [ref](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/artisan#writing-commands)

Comment: its in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/artisan#arguments) how to pass optional argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can create using ? operator,

```
protected $signature = 'make:custom-model {name?} {userRelation?} {productRelation?} {categoryRelation?} {fillableFromDb?} {castingFields?}';
```